# How to build multiple package binaries at once

Tags: go

I've seen this discussed in various places, with answers like 'use a cmd/foo, cmd/bar' type folder structure.

This does not work for me.

This works:

```
$ du -a
8   ./src/cmd/bin1/main.go
8   ./src/cmd/bin1
8   ./src/cmd/bin2/main.go
8   ./src/cmd/bin2
16  ./src/cmd
8   ./src/shared/foo/foo.go
8   ./src/shared/foo
8   ./src/shared
24  ./src
```

and building it:

```
go build ./src/cmd/bin2
go build ./src/cmd/bin1
```

However, I can't figure out what variation on:

```
go build ./src/...
```

I might need to build all such binaries in one step.

This layout:

```
$ du -a
8   ./cmd/bin1/main.go
8   ./cmd/bin1
8   ./cmd/bin2/main.go
8   ./cmd/bin2
16  ./cmd
8   ./src/shared/foo/foo.go
8   ./src/shared/foo
8   ./src/shared
8   ./src
24  .
```

Seems totally unusable. No combination of `go build ...` commands seems to build bin1 or bin2.

The best I can get is `go build cmd/bin1/main.go` which gives me a binary called 'main'. Not helpful.

So, specifically and in detail, including the `go build` command, that actually builds the individual binaries, how do you do this?

...and why is the default advice that people keep giving to use a top level `cmd` folder? How do you build these binaries if you do?

Comment: check out `https://github.com/spf13/cobra` you will point it at `cmd/main.go` and other command source files will be used as e.g. `main doX` `main printY`

Comment: You can add subcommands with cobra, but it does not produce multiple binaries as intended.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't want to install the binaries into `$GOPATH/bin`, you could do what other open source projects do, which is create a script.

Most of the projects out there have make files and build scripts for producing multiple binaries.

In your case, you could build a script that iterates over the packages in `cmd`, and run `go build` on each.

```
cd $GOPATH/someProject
for CMD in `ls cmd`; do
  go build ./cmd/$CMD
done
```

This results in:

```
[root@node1 test]# ls $GOPATH/someProject
bin1  bin2  cmd
```

Couple of trending projects that you can look at:

- Grafana - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/build.go
- Torus - https://github.com/coreos/torus/blob/master/Makefile
- Caddy - https://github.com/mholt/caddy/blob/master/dist/automate.go

Answer (score 16):

You can use `-o` flag of `go build`. From official documentation:

> The `-o` flag forces build to write the resulting executable or object to the
> named output file or directory, instead of the default behavior described in
> the last two paragraphs. If the named output is a directory that exists, then
> any resulting executables will be written to that directory.

So you can try something like:

```
go build  -o . ./...
```

This essentially making Go to write resulting executables in current folder
(the `.` value of `-o`) for all packages in the current module/folder/project.

Answer (score 9):

The command:

```
go install ./...
```

should build all binaries under your current directory (i.e. `./...`) and put them on `$GOPATH/bin`.

Answer (score 9):

From the `go build` help:

> When compiling multiple packages or a single non-main package,
>   build compiles the packages but discards the resulting object,
>   serving only as a check that the packages can be built.

In order to build all packages under a directory, you can run `go install ./...`. All of your packages will be built and installed (i.e. put under $GOPATH/bin).

With your example, you'd have two executables produced: `$GOPATH/bin/bin1` and `$GOPATH/bin/bin2`

There is also the alternative of writing a simple Makefile to do what you want.