# Is there a way with Go to build more than one executable with one “go build” command? (as with Rust)?

Tags: go, build, target

With Rust,it is possible to generate a plurality of binary targets by simply designating them in the cargo.toml file associated with the target:

```
[[bin]]
name = "daemon"
path = "src/daemon/bin/main.rs"

[[bin]]

name = "client"
path = "src/client/bin/main.rs"
```

Is there a way to achieve the same with Go modules, i.e. build more than one executable with one “go build” command?

Example of the problem

```
//main1.o
//package main

func main() {
    println("From main1")
}

// - - 

//main2.o
//package main

func main() {
    println("From main2")
}

// ---
go build:
// ---

//Result:


./main2.go:3:6: main redeclared in this block
    /Users/sergehulne/Documents/code/Go/tst/main1.go:3:6: previous declaration
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies), you can pass multiple packages to `go build`. Can you try this?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't build multiple executable files with "go build". A solution to your problem with be to build a bash script. Here is an article that might be helpful https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-go-executables-for-multiple-platforms-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: So there’s no other solution than dividing your project into a plurality of modules (one for each binary executable needed by the project).

Comment: Many modules have multiple main packages, you just build them individually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build multiple package binaries at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680437/how-to-build-multiple-package-binaries-at-once)

Comment: I don’t think  that the current definition of a module (i.e. a directory in which one has run the command go mod init mymodule) allows for more than one single main function per module.

Comment: @SergeHulne: I'm not sure where you're getting that from. Take [kubernetes for example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes), which has 22 different main packages in the `cmd` directory, all part of the same module.

Comment: More than one main() in a module will trigger a warning in VSCode, for instance.

Comment: If it's a valid module, then that is an issue with vscode. I have many developers using vscode on major projects, with many main packages in modules without a problem.

Comment: //main1.o
//package main

func main() {
 println("From main1")
}

// - - 

//main2.o
//package main

func main() {
 println("From main2")
}

// ---
go build:
// ---

//Result:


./main2.go:3:6: main redeclared in this block
 /Users/sergehulne/Documents/code/Go/tst/main1.go:3:6: previous declaration

Comment: I have edited the initial question with a formatted example of the question...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution is to ignore the warnings associated with having more than one main() function in one Go module and to compile the files separately as if they were kind of sub-modules.

```
go mod init tst
```

```
package main
// file main1.go
func main() {
    println("From main1")
}
```

```
package main
// file main2.go
func main() {
    println("From main2")
}
```

and then sequentially:

```
go build main1.go
```

```
go build main2.go
```

Which yield respectively main1 and main2 (two executables)

It's awkward, but it works.

Comment: That generates warnings because it's not a valid package. You cannot have multiple `main` _functions_ in a single main package. You should be building packages, not files.

Comment: @JimB : That would imply main1:go and main.go have to reside inside separate, dedicated, folders, which defeats the purpose of a module (a module as opposed to a package).

Comment: A module is a collection of packages, and a package consists of a single directory containing go files. Like it or not, that is how the language tooling defines it.

Comment: @Jimb : So basically the smallest Go programming unit is a directory, not a file (unlike C, C++, Python). It does not seem very handy for experimenting, toying around.

Comment: Go will happily build individual files in an implicit package, as you've shown here, for experimenting or quick one-off programs. It still doesn't change that your directory with multiple `main`s is not a valid package itself.